# Weka LibSVM one class classifier always predicts one class

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm, weka

I'm trying to use LibSVM classifier in Weka to build a one class SVM classifier.

My training file has list of **noun words**. 
My test file has many words. My aim is to use the classifier to predict the words which are nouns in test file.

My input arff file (*ip.arff*)(training file) looks like this:

```
@relation test1

@attribute name string
@attribute class {yes}

@data
'building',yes
'car',yes
..... and so on
```

My test file(*test.arff*) (test file) looks like this:

```
@relation test2

@attribute name string
@attribute class {yes}

@data
'car',?
'window',?
'running',?
..... and so on
```

Here's what I've done:

1. Since the datatype is string, I used *batch Filtering* on both input files to generate
   *ipstd.arff* and *teststd.arff* as mentioned in
   [http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering][1]
2. Next i load and run the classifier with *ipstd.arff*. (Note: All the words are classified as yes)
3. Next I load the test set *teststd.arff* and re-evaluate the model.
4. But all the words are classified as nouns('yes')

   `=== Predictions on user test set ===`

   `inst#     actual  predicted error prediction`

   ```
     1        1:?      1:yes       1 
     2        1:?      1:yes       1
     3        1:?      1:yes       1
   ```

   `and so on`

**My problem is that all words in test file(*teststd.arff*) are classified as nouns**

Can someone tell where I'm going wrong..
What should I do classify noun words in test set with 'yes' and others as outliers.
Thanks...

Comment: Although phrased in terms of Weka, the problem here may be the logic the OP is using, not the code. This question may be better here than SO.

Comment: gung:  supported. This is on-topic, even if it may need rewording.

Comment: i have some problem , how do you solved your probplem ?